# How to set binding for a chart mapping's itemdatasource in Telerik RadChart?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, telerik

I have this XAML from a sample:

```
            <chart:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
                <charting:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Population">
                    <charting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="YValue" FieldName="Population" />
                    <charting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="XCategory" FieldName="Country" />
                </charting:SeriesMapping>
                <charting:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Vehicles in circulation" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource2}">
                    <charting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="YValue" FieldName="Vehicles" />
                    <charting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="XCategory" FieldName="Country" />
                </charting:SeriesMapping>
                <charting:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Road network length (km)" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource3}">
                    <charting:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                        <charting:BarSeriesDefinition AxisName="Secondary" ItemLabelFormat="#Y{0,.# k}" />
                    </charting:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                    <charting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="YValue" FieldName="RoadNetwork" />
                    <charting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="XCategory" FieldName="Country" />
                </charting:SeriesMapping>
            </chart:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
```

Right now I have the entire chart binded to a single source, but I can see in the example it's possible to bind each mapping to a different source:

```
<charting:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Vehicles in circulation" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource2}">
```

I am trying to find out how to do this programatically.  Because my mappings are dynamic (I don't know if I'll have 1 or 10 or any number of mappings) I am trying to set each one in the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this one:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(mapping, SeriesMapping.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("DataSource2"));
```

Where mapping is a new SeriesMapping()